# PHP Data Extraction in TD

Tags: php, html

This is table structure I am getting from the HTML page source-

```
<table id="company">              
    <tr class="alt">
        <td width="60%"><b>Trading Code:</b> BATBC</td>
        <td width="40%"><b>Scrip Code:</b> 14259</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here is my code in PHP. Consider $HTML is the above source-

```
foreach($HTML->find('table[id=company]' ) as $Company){
    foreach( $Company->find('td') as $td ) {
        if( preg_match( '/Trading Code/', $td )){
            echo $td .PHP_EOL;                      
        }
        if( preg_match( '/Scrip Code/', $td )){
            echo $td .PHP_EOL;                  
        }
    }
}
```

My intention is to get Trading Code, BATBC
and  Scrip Code, 14259
but I am getting only the text parts enclosed in bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to get exactly the data from the parsed html element. I adjusted your code a little to get the data you mentioned.

```php
foreach($HTML->find('table[id=company]' ) as $Company){
  foreach( $Company->find('td') as $td ) {
    if( preg_match( '/<b>(Trading Code|Scrip Code):<\/b> ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/', $td, $match)){
      echo $match[1].'='.$match[2].PHP_EOL;
    }
  }
}
```